# Ideal "RequestOptions" values in Azure cosmosdb Async java?

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb

When upserting documents to Azure cosmos DB, what should be the best RequestOptions Values to be set? 
There is not much information on the official Microsoft documentation 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.requestoptions?view=azure-java-stable
If anyone experienced this, please share your ideas. I want to know about the RequestOptions and its properties. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's is the same for any programming language based on your requirement. For example, you could set the partitionkey

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.setScriptLoggingEnabled(true);
requestOptions.setPartitionKey(new PartitionKey("Seattle"));
```

Read the options in **[detail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.requestoptions?view=azure-dotnet)**

Comment: Thanks for the response.  But what if I pass empty RequestOptions object. Are there any default values for RequestOptions, ex: RequestOptions.setConsistencyLevel()  is there any default value like Session/Eventual ?